# How to print 2 horizontal lines

Tags: python

I have range of number 132-149
And i have to print 2 horizontal lines
first for even numbers and second for odd numbers
I can print odd and even numbers separately using:

```
>>> for num in range (132, 150):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print (num, end = ' ')


132 134 136 138 140 142 144 146 148 
>>> for num in range (132, 150):
    if num % 2 != 0:
        print (num, end = ' ')


133 135 137 139 141 143 145 147 149 

want these two to combine and printe something like this:

132 134 136 138 140 142 144 146 148
133 135 137 139 141 143 145 147 149
```

Comment: Could you please show the expected output besides of the code you have written so far? Also you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your edit. 
First of all you don't need to iterate over your numbers multiple times. You just can use pythons [if/else](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) construct.

```
even_list = []  
odd_list = []
for num in range(132, 150):
       if num % 2 == 0:
          even_list.append(str(num))  # casted to string to use join function later
       else:
          odd_list.append(str(num))

print(" ".join(even_list))
print(" ".join(odd_list))
```

## Output

```
132 134 136 138 140 142 144 146 148
133 135 137 139 141 143 145 147 149
```

Comment: yeah it works but i have to write - > print(" ".join(even_list))
print(" ".join(odd_list) these first and i dont want that i want program to do it himself

Comment: So just a single print statement?

Comment: yes within the program  like   my program does  gives even and odd numbers automatically

Comment: With one print statement you can change the code to `print(" ".join(even_list),"\n", " ".join(odd_list))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by appending to 2 different lists:

```
line1=[]
line2=[]
for num in range (132, 150):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        line1.append(num)
    else:
        line2.append(num)

print(line1)
print(line2)
```

Comment: The result is just too long

Comment: I am getting the output u wanted:

    [132, 134, 136, 138, 140, 142, 144, 146, 148]
    [133, 135, 137, 139, 141, 143, 145, 147, 149]

Do you want the output in some other format?

Comment: no i want it like that but i have to write -> print(line1)
print(line2) these first to get what i want  i want program to do that himself without me writing  - > print(line1) print(line2)   these

Answer (score 0):

```py
def print_even_odd(start, end):
    e_o = []
    if start % 2 != 0:
        e_o.append(('', start))
    for i in range((start + 1) / 2, (end + 1) / 2):
        e_o.append((i * 2, i * 2 + 1))
    if end % 2 == 0:
        e_o.append((end, ''))

    for i in e_o:
        print("\t%5s\t\t%5s" % i)

    for j in [0, 1]:
        result = "".join(["%5s" % i[j] for i in e_o])
        print(result)


print_even_odd(1, 20)
```

result is:

```py
                    1
        2           3
        4           5
        6           7
        8           9
       10          11
       12          13
       14          15
       16          17
       18          19
       20            
         2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17   19
```

I hope that, this is what you need

Comment: i want them to be horizontally

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
print '*' * n
```

where `n` is the number of asterisks you wish to display.

Here is a more complete example:

```
lens = [3, 5, 10, 1]
for i, l in enumerate(lens):
    print '%02d:%s' % (i + 1, '*' * l)
```

This displays:

```
01:***
02:*****
03:**********
```

Comment: Why should he print asterisks? And the output of your code is `01:***
02:*****
03:**********
04:*`